# How to find which crystal planes are symmetric

Tags: solid-state-physics, crystals, x-ray-crystallography

Is there a strict mathematical procedure to find all equivalent planes given a unit cell and a particular plane of interest?

For example, consider a conventional FCC unit cell and the (100) plane. I can see that the (010) and (001) planes would be identical to this 100 plane.

One of things I found are tables with symmetry-equivalent reflections, such as given [here](http://pd.chem.ucl.ac.uk/pdnn/symm2/multj.htm). Can these also be used to identify symmetry relations between planes? If so, how do you employ these?